# Zsh: hash directory completion

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have configured some directories alias via `hash -d hashname=/path/to/directory` command.
Completion for that aliases works for a long time like this:

```
% hashn<TAB> # becomes hashname, pressing <ENTER> works like cd /path/to/directory
```

Some times ago this has stopped to work. Now that aliases are completable only if starts with `~` sign:

```
% ~hashn<TAB> # only this works
```

Is there any way to get previous behaviour?

Comment: Running `hashname` after `hash -d hashname=…` wouldn't treat `hashname` as a named directory, not even under `setopt autocd`. Are you sure you hadn't made `hashname` an alias? If you do run `hashname` now, what does it do? What is the output of `type hashname`?

Comment: for now `type hashname` returns `hashname not found`. I am definetely sure that I hadn't made alias for `hashname`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had the options [`auto_cd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fCD) and [`cdable_vars`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CDABLE_005fVARS) turned on. With `auto_cd`, if you type a directory as a command name, the `cd` command is implied. With `cdable_vars`, if a directory doesn't exist, or a command doesn't exist with `auto_cd`, then the name is looked up in the directory hash table.

As long as you're using the “new-style” (`compinit`) completion system, which oh-my-zsh turns on, the name will be offered as a completion when relevant.

Comment: Adding `setopt autocd cdable_vars` does the job, thank you!